# How To Exclude Some Exe From My Path [Windows]

Tags: windows, path, msys2

My Problem is i have msys2/mingw-w64/bin the whole folder in my path, and as it turns out even though i didnt explicitly installed python through msys2 its there in the path and many other bin which i dont need, Its messing with my actually installed python install and i want want it in my path. So i was wondering if there is a way for me to exclude some exe from the folder which is in the path. I mainly use mays2 for its gcc gdb and clang lldb, cmake, stuff. Any helpful liks or comments are much apricated. Please describe the process for someone who dosent have a lot of experience.

Comment: Can you turn the problem round and explicitly set the PATH for python when you need it (and likewise mingw)?

Comment: i mean yes thats a correct solution, and also i can use the path hierarchy to get my requested results,  but isnt there a way for me to exclude some exe ?, like there has to be a way i was searching for that. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: No, I don't think Windows supports excluding certain executables from your PATH.  I suggest that you just use the Python provided by MSYS2 instead of using a separately installed Python; then there should be no conflicts.

Comment: i was thinking something like a path switcher or how scoop handles its env variables but thanks.